# Mouse suddenly unusable

Tags: mouse, 19.10

My mouse is suddenly almost completely unusable, and the system is also dropping keystrokes, signalling major input lag (cursor moves a few pixels every half second). However, the system seems to be running smoothly, with very little memory usage (939Mib/7.8Gib) and almost no cpu usage.

Comment: Can you post the relevant last lines of your system log?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo -i
echo N> /sys/module/drm_kms_helper/parameters/poll
echo "options drm_kms_helper poll=N">/etc/modprobe.d/local.conf
```

If you are using a newer kernel, you can execcute the commands below since the drm_kms_helper is loaded automatically

Note that on newer kernels the `drm_kms_helper` module may not be loaded by default. One extra step gets this working:

```
sudo -i
modprobe drm_kms_helper
echo N> /sys/module/drm_kms_helper/parameters/poll
echo "drm_kms_helper" >> /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf
echo "options drm_kms_helper poll=N" >> /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf
```